# I need to use a string input from an HTML form to sned it to a Node.js/Exress server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

(Im new on everything related to databases and servers, sorry if i say anything stupid) Im trying to make a login for a simple chrome extension im making. For now, i just need to send a password string that is writen on an input box to a express server.

The HTMl code:

```html
<form action="/CTRL" method="SEND">
     User: <input type="text" name="User" value="User"><br>
     Password: <input type="text" name="Password" value="Password"><br>
     <button type="submit" value="Submit">ENVIAR</button>
</form>
```

The node code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/CTRL', function(req, res){
        res.send();
    });

    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("Funciono!");
    });
```

Comment: `method="SEND"` is not valid. It should be either `method="GET"` or `method="POST"`

Comment: Since you're using `app.get()`, it should be `method="GET"`

Comment: The form fields are in `req.params.User` and `req.params.Password`.

Comment: But you should use `method="POST"` for a login form, otherwise the password will appear in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your form's `method` property to `GET`